# gclid and fbclid at same time

Tags: facebook, ads, google-ads-api, facebook-ads

During checking traffic source on e-commerce website i get confused.

I know that param gclid=.. means that user is tagged by GoogleAds, while fbclid works the same way but with facebook.

However, I dont understand what does it mean while they are both together in single url, like:
[www.example.com?gclid=CjwKCAiAyrXiBRAjEiwATI95mafT26kwak0CFBgICH0ZlLqafSBuyyoUBVZihf22pPdG9QK8DUmiZBoCh8YQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&fbclid=IwAR0oihEZbw0Q43GXiv4YW9n_G9odTEcpxzLtMxjYYqgrTt5EM-BcKqrJyuU](http://www.example.com?gclid=CjwKCAiAyrXiBRAjEiwATI95mafT26kwak0CFBgICH0ZlLqafSBuyyoUBVZihf22pPdG9QK8DUmiZBoCh8YQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&fbclid=IwAR0oihEZbw0Q43GXiv4YW9n_G9odTEcpxzLtMxjYYqgrTt5EM-BcKqrJyuU)

Is it possible that google ads is displaying ads on facebook and that is why gclid and fbclid are attached to url at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite possible and normal.

If user searches on web via Google, clicks on Ad and is redirected to page, for example `https://example.com/index?gclid=randomstring` then it displays at the top of their browser.

Now user can copy this link and share it via Messenger (more common case) or facebook to someone. Then Facebook will not remove `gclid` and append `fbclid`.

As a result, you get a link with both these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same question on support google and get reply from them.

> This case happens when a link including gclid is pasted on a Facebook
> page and somebody clicks on the link.

[Source to answer.](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/78241237?hl=pl)